# Redirect to specific page and write code onload of that page in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

On redirection of one page other, some code should be executed but it was not possible

```
if (something === true) {
  /* Redirect to someotherpage.php */  
  window.location.href = "someotherpage.php"  
  var test = "someotherpage.php";  

  /* onload of someotherpage.php, execute this introjs step */  
  $(test).load(function() {  
    if (window.location.href === test) {  
      /* unable to execute this */  
      introJs().addStep({  
        element: $('#ck-dashboard-pending-task')[0],  
        intro: 'Here you can see the todo list',  
        position: 'left'  
      }).setOption('scrollToElement', true).start();  
    }  
  });  
}
```

Comment: Once `window.location.href` has been set it will stop executing the JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to execute a code inside a page when another page is loaded. You can't do that this way (You could do it in single-page apps, but that's another story).

In your `someotherpage.php` you should add this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
      introJs().addStep({  
      element:$('#ck-dashboard-pending-task')[0],  
      intro:'Here you can see the todo list',  
      position:'left'  
      }).setOption('scrollToElement', true).start();
  });
```

And you should remove this portion of your code in your page:
var test = "someotherpage.php";

```
/* onload of someotherpage.php, execute this introjs step */  
  $(test).load(function() {  
    if (window.location.href === test) {  
      /* unable to execute this */  
      introJs().addStep({  
        element: $('#ck-dashboard-pending-task')[0],  
        intro: 'Here you can see the todo list',  
        position: 'left'  
      }).setOption('scrollToElement', true).start();  
    }  
  });
```

EDIT:
As asked by the OP, here's a clarification:
In your first page, you could do something like this:

```
if (something === true) {
  /* Redirect to someotherpage.php */  
  window.location.href = "someotherpage.php?some_condition_you_want_to_check=1"
}
```

On `someotherpage.php`:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    $.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (results==null){
           return null;
        }
        else{
           return results[1] || 0;
        }
    }

    if($.urlParam('some_condition_you_want_to_check') !== null){
        introJs().addStep({  
            element:$('#ck-dashboard-pending-task')[0],  
            intro:'Here you can see the todo list',  
            position:'left'  
            }).setOption('scrollToElement', true).start();
        });  
    }
  }
```

Of course mine is an untested and surely to-be-improved portion of code, but that should give you the idea of what you need to do to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hey thanks micheal, but I need to execute that load event only on that if(something == true) condition. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You should apply any page-specific logic inside such page. If you need to pass something from page1 to page2, you could add a GET parameter from page1 and check it in page2.

Comment: I wrote that code in a namespace so the **from** page is random and don't know how to pass parameter to other page, Can you give a small example.